# Show all elements of network in Python

Tags: python, windows

I have a network storage that looks like the picture below (changed the names for privacy reasons).
How can I use Python to print out a list with all the shared folders?
i.e. `list = [A, B, C, D, E, F]`

Eventually, I would like to iterate through the folders A-F and open them.

[image]

Comment: What's the end result of the *whole* program? Is it to get the directory paths of the folders (End result ```["C:/Network/xy11/A", "C:/Network/xy11/B",``` etc.), get the folder names (End result ```["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"]```), Get the names of the files inside the folders, Or get the contents of the files inside the folders?